# Hide pull requests in Github

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Is there a way to only let certain teams view pull requests or specifically, to be able to view comments on pull requests? Or if not, is there a way to hide the comments on an individual pull request to everyone but a select few individuals?

I am a TA, and our current practice is to have all students submit pull requests that contain their test answers. Then, I write comments on their pull request regarding their scores on each question. I would prefer the tests are not visible to other students, but at the very least I would like these comments to not be visible to the other students but to be visible to other instructors (on a separate team).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a project called [refined-github](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github), looks like it's Chrome extension, that lets you hide inline comments, see their discussion (sounds like it's already implemented) [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/refined-github/issues/212).

This may not be what you're asking, but it looks like you can also strip all comments from a PR with the JavaScript found [here](https://gist.github.com/Darep/b33ba3d71f4570760422317aa7bf31f2).

In terms of letting some folks see certain things and others not, I think one needs to do that by repository, and then you give a certain team (to which you add certain members) a set of permissions on the repository. Here's [GitHub's matrix of permissions](https://help.github.com/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization/); I'm not seeing how one can just grant or remove the permission to view PR comments.

Hope some of this is helpful in your situation!